How can I get Nautilus's file search integration with GNOME, but not have it as a file manager?
I prefer to use Nemo rather than the default Nautilus as a file manager. But if I uninstall Nautilus, then I lose the GNOME search ability, i.e. hitting the Super key and then doing this:

I want Nautilus to act as if it's not installed for all purposes other than this. I don't want it showing up the application launcher if I search for "files", and I don't want any folder opening in Nautlius by default (which I find starts happening again the moment I re-install Nautilus).
I tried setting NoDisplay=true in the Nautilus .desktop file, but I found that also disables search.
Ubuntu 24.04
